# How to force-on an addon in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

Firefox recently banned RT news addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/blocked-addon/%7Ba53eff1b-c95c-4297-8ac1-66d60268f391%7D/1.7/

I used this addon to get access to news faster.

How can I force it on?

PS: I read from russian, iranian, syrian, israeli, USA, argentinian pro-west (like Infobae) and then I form my opinion. Seems that Mozilla is taking part in the news war and trying to ban other news / opinions.

Answer (score 1):

From internet:

> Hi guys! There is my solution:
>
> ```
> in address bar type: about:config
> search: extensions.blocklist.enabled switch to false
> make laugh)))
> If addon have been removed - about:addons - install add-on from file... (browser-mon@xdman.sourceforge.net.xpi required).
> Enjoy)))
> ```

https://github.com/subhra74/xdm/issues/454